# Why should i upgrade to Sharepoint 2010 for an intranet site

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, moss, sharepoint-2010

What possible reasons can be there for me to upgrade my intranet to SP 2010 from MOSS 2007. Are there some big leaps in functionality and/or performance?

Comment: Did you try googling "What's new in Sharepoint 2010" or "Sharepoint 2007 vs 2010"? Then you will find gems like the feature comparison matrix at http://www.khamis.net/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=4

Answer (score 2):

For users:

- Better UI (Ribbon, Silverlight, improved theming)
- Improved non-IE browsers support

For developers:

- Major improvement in development tools (in VS2010)
- Silverlight support
- Client object model
- Development dashboard

For admins:

- Improved Central Administration
- Improved logging
- Resource throttling (large lists)
- Best Practices Analyzer
- Requires more hardware (especially RAM)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what cement has said,

For Users:

- Social integration in MySites
- Enterprise content management
  improvements (tagging).
- Better cross-browser improvements.